# Android Gradle product Flavors with Parse Push Notifications

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I am trying to send Push notifications via Parse and integrating product flavors. When I implement product flavors, i am not able to receive Parse Push Notifications. Does anyone have any advise on correcting this issue

Gradle app file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.project"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
productFlavors{
    freeApp{
        applicationId "com.example.project.free"

    }
    premiumApp{
        applicationId "com.example.project.paid"
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.2-66-g4b6eb97.jar')
compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.2.0.jar')
compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.2.jar')
compile files('libs/ParseCrashReporting-1.9.2.jar')
}
```

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.project"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.1" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission android:name="com.example.project.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.project.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:name="com.example.project.Application"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">



    <activity
        android:name="com.example.project.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <!--
              IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
            -->
            <category android:name="com.example.project" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: I've tried everything. I ended up not using GCM with parse. Just remove all the GCM related stuff from the manifest and parse will fallback to using their network instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** As has been observed, my solution is somewhat more complicated than the one by Morten Holmgaard below. Needless to say, had I known of the simpler solution I would have proposed that one. However, my answer does contain some relevant explanation and it also was the only - and only *correct* - answer for five weeks, so I will leave it up.

===========================================================================

**What's the problem?**

I think the reason you are not receiving any pushes is that in your AndroidManifest.xml you declare the following for Parse:

```
<permission android:name="com.example.project.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.project.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

        <!--
          IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
        -->
        <category android:name="com.example.project" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The package names, however, are defined as

```
applicationId "com.example.project.free"
```

and

```
applicationId "com.example.project.paid"
```

So the package names don't match the declarations in your AndroidManifest.xml and therefore Parse is unable to receive pushes. Actually, if you look at your logcat output, you should be seeing a message from Parse that tells you exactly what is missing in your AndroidManifest.xml.

**So, how to solve this?**

This is a bit of a tricky situation but it can be done:

1.) Remove the two parts I quoted above from the AndroidManifest.xml in your `main` source set (`src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`).

2a.) Create an AndroidManifest.xml in your `free` source set (`src/free/AndroidManifest.xml`) and enter the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.project.free.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.project.free.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.example.project.free" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

2b.) Do the same for the `paid` source set. Be sure to replace the package name correctly in the AndroidManifest.xml.

**Why does this work?**

Because gradle does not replace the `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` with the `src/free/AndroidManifest.xml` but instead *merges* them into one. So if you just leave the declarations out of the `main` source set and put them in to `free` and `paid` you will get a correctly merged AndroidManifest.xml for each flavor.

Comment: This will not work because the R class will be created per package name (the manifest attribute). Having different package names per flavor means you cannot have shared code which accesses the R class.

Comment: So you are saying that I cannot give different flavors different package name via the `applicationId`? Because I can assure you it is possible, and we have done so multiple times. In fact, I have also used the exact setup described above for Parse pushes.

Comment: Oh wait, you said the _manifest attribute_ called `package name`. In that case: That may be true, if I were changing that attribute - but I am not, I am only declaring and using a new permission.

Comment: If you use the packageName you declared in the manifest (AKA the package location for the R class and the generated Manifest class) for GCM permission, it will work. But both products will not be able to install side by side on Android 5.

Comment: Yes, that is true (at least if the two APKs are signed with different keys - if they are signed with the same key Android L _does_ allow multiple APKs to declare the same permission). And that is also why you _must not_ change the `package` attribute in the `AndroidManifest.xml` files in the build flavor source sets but - like cold_brew did - change it in the `build.gradle` by declaring a different `applicationId` for each flavor. Also, if you do it like that, the package name of your `R` does not change and you will be able to build both flavors.

Comment: I didn't really intend that repository to be very public and some parts of the code may be messy, but here is a working example: https://github.com/DavidMihola/BrandingExampleProject

Comment: This is so much more complicated than [the super simple answer by @Morten which works perfectly.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32168373/383414)

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. An appropriate warning has been added to alert future readers.

Answer (score 8):

I have just solved the exact same problem very easily with the [Manifest Merger](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger):

```
 ${applicationId}
```

Example:

```
    <permission
        android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

Comment: While my answer above, too, is *correct*, I agree that this should be the *accepted* answer.

Comment: What would be the package name in manifest when we are using `${applicationId}`

Comment: @Clairvoyant Your package name or if you use productFlavors or buildTypes: The applicationId assigned there.

Comment: This should be in @Parse "how to" guide. Can't believe they left something this important out....