# Having trouble creating Gradle flavors for different manifests in a single app

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-productflavors

I'm following [these instructions](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html) for creating flavors and Android Studio keeps complaining that it can't find 
/path/to/my/project/app/src/main

instead of **main** as per the directions I have a folder called **portrait** and a folder called **landscape**
in other words

> /path/to/my/project/app/src/portrait/[res,java,assets,AndroidManifest.xml]

and

> /path/to/my/project/app/src/landscape/[res,java,assets,AndroidManifest.xml]

my gradle file contains:

```
productFlavors {
    portrait {
        applicationId "com.my.project"
        versionName "1.0-portrait"
    }
    landscape {
        applicationId "com.my.project"
        versionName "1.0-landscape"
    }
}
```

And yet when I try to MAKE the project I get

> Error:Cause: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /Users/me/git/MY/PROJECT/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml (No such
>   file or directory)

I've tried noodling with the directory structure, but am unable to clear this complaint. I'm entirely unclear on why it's looking for "main"... where's it getting that directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `main` sourceSet is not optional, all your java code and resources should go there. Only flavor specific code and resources should go to your flavors. Then Gradle will merge them according to http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging

So, if you don't have `main`, Gradle will complain.

Comment: I see... ok, so, where do I put the differently flavored manifests? I've tried shifting them about but everything I try AS complains that it can't find a manifest file unless it's right under main... so, how do I get 2 of them?

Comment: You must have an AndroidManifest.xml under "main", which is "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml". Here you define most of your components. If you want to define some components specific to your flavor, you can put another AndroidManifest.xml, e.g. "src/portrait/AndroidManifest.xml". Here you define only flavor specific activities because manifests will be merged. So, the merged manifest will have both components from selected flavor + components from main

Comment: I'm not sure that you should use flavors in your case though because flavor names look a bit confusing for me.. When you pick a build variant which is build type + product flavor, you specify what variant you want to use to build your apk. That means you will have to build different apk files for portait and landscape because your flavors are named this way.. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: yeah, this is actually exactly what I want - This is a "building blocks" app that I use as a starting point for various apps. I'm trying to reduce the amount of configuration I need to do as I migrate it to its new life. However the solo manifest files under their own flavor directories don't appear happy either. But this is a whole new error, so, I'll deal with it.

Comment: Also, look here for an example of what merging manifests would look like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061546/android-gradle-product-flavors-with-parse-push-notifications