# INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION on include app on the settings.gradle

Tags: android

I have created an android SDK that is having the below permission. Any new apps can use my sdk.

my installation failing when another app with this sdk integration already installed on android device

```
./adb install /Users/renjith//playground/MyApplication/app/app-release.apk 
1714 KB/s (1451039 bytes in 0.826s)
pkg: /data/local/tmp/app-release.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION perm=org.example.demosdk.C2D_MESSAGE pkg=com.org.sdktest]
```

Comment: Yes, that may well be the case. At least on Lollipop+ devices. Without knowing which SDK you are trying to integrate and which apps are in conflict and what their `AndroidManifest.xml`'s look like, I can only point you to this question and the answers there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061546/android-gradle-product-flavors-with-parse-push-notifications

Answer (score 0):

After Uninstalling App You may find App Name under Apps List of the Downloaded Tab.

- Go to Settings
- Apps
- At bottom of the list you will find YourApp with a "NOT INSTALLED"
  Tag
- Open
- Click on OptionMenu and Select "Uninstall for all Users"

After that process  install the new app.

Thanks.

Comment: it is an sdk. So both the apps are different